# progress bar change of height

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

This progress bar works as expected but the css is not being applied. It needs to show the inside white text which is being set by javascript.

All what I am getting is the thin progress bar thus the height property is not working. Any suggestions? thx

```css
#bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<progress id="bar" value="0" max="70"></progress>
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. but it still does not work. I am expecting a much thicker bar but the result the same thin one.

Comment: What browser are you testing with? In mine, if I replace the 1.5rem with 3rem it becomes twice as high.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `-webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none;` as below:

```css
#bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: green;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<progress id="bar" value="20" max="70"></progress>
```

Comment: unknowned css property 'appearance'

Comment: if you are on firefox, try `-moz-appearance`. If IE, no luck.

Comment: Here in the future, this [should work fine](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_appearance_compat-auto) without prefixes on [almost*] all browsers.  (*IE still isn't supported in the future...)

Comment: ...but that's okay now, since the further-future doesn't support IE.  *finally!*

Answer (score 0):

You can add text with css selector :before

```css
#bar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }

#bar:before {
        content: 'Value is ' attr(value);
    }
```

```html
<progress id="bar" value="65" max="70">test</progress>
```